# Do Americans/Brits/Canadians need a guide and/or visa to travel Qeshm Island (Iran)?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, iran

I am an American passport holder who visited Iran in 2015 and loved it. I want to go back and see more of the country. A travel agent friend suggested I go to Qeshm Island because I would not need a guide nor a visa (since it is a free trade zone). Has anyone been there? Did you enjoy it? Did you have to have a guide?

I am getting conflicting information about this. The Iranian Interests Section in Washington DC said I needed a guide and visa.  My travel agent friend said she called the Iranian Foreign Ministry and they said I didn't need a guide or visa if I only visit Qeshm Island.

I am curious if any Americans/Brits/Canadians have been to Qeshm Island recently and traveled without a guide or visa.

Comment: [Relevant reading](http://hitchhikershandbook.com/2015/06/30/travel-in-iran-independently-british-american-canadian/)

Comment: @blackbird Great article; But, actually, she is asking about Qeshm Island which is  known as  free zone

Comment: @blackbird I have heard rumors of Americans/Brits/Canadians going without guides. I read through all of the comments on this HHH post and the travel agent stopped offering to get visa approval without a full time guide. At the end someone said she couldn't get visas at all for Americans/Brits/Canadians now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kish and Qeshm Islands are free zones, as you mentioned, and based on the Iran Free Zones' rules travelers of all nationalities can visit these regions without visa and guide. You can visit http://www.irantourcenter.com/one-of-the-best-beach-resorts-in-iran/ (I work in this travel agency) for more information about Qeshm.
our rep in Tehran went directly to MFA and you can be 100 percent sure of being able to visit Qeshm without visa and guide as an american citizen with the direct flight from DXB.

Comment: It looks like the quote from Mr. Habibi is from 2014.

Comment: @Connie Yes, I found that in IRNA website and it is for 2014

Comment: @irantourcenter If you are absolutely sure of this, you need to contact the MFA and ask them to send Timatic an update request, or OP is likely to be **denied boarding** on the flight to Qeshm

Comment: I called MFA and the staff confirmed what i said, but to be sure I will asked the MFA officer tomorrow and let you know the detail.

Comment: @irantourcenter Then you need to update the answer later.

Comment: @Connie our rep in Tehran went directly to MFA and you can be 100 percent sure of being able to visit Qeshm without visa and guide as an american citizen with the direct flight from DXB.

Comment: @samane Like I said, Timatic (IATA) **must** be informed and update the database, since that's what airlines use. If they check and it says you cannot board, **you are not getting on the plane, period!**

Comment: Since the OP has disclosed his/her affiliation and the answer is helpful, I'm going to leave this answer untouched.

Comment: @Crazydre  This situation is exactly what I am afraid of!

Comment: @Connie I recently sent the Timatic team a Review request (I have a contact guy within it) - so they're now going to find out from their goverment sources, black on white, and update their info if necessary. If they find that you can indeed visit Qeshm visa-free, they'll update it and the airlines will see the new info. Will Keep you posted

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks, I checked the Timatic now, but they still say that **[Visa required](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)** Did they update that? Or it is it still old data?

Comment: @Kermani Still waiting for a Reply from the Timatic team. Sometimes they only take a day, other times a couple of weeks

Comment: @Crazydre I understand and that is logical to take a long time because there are lots of different cities in the world and they need to research about it to find the right answer.

Comment: @Kermani I did to, they answered very quickly but the rules are not changed yet.

Comment: @samane, the user *Crazydre* meant **Timatic**; BTW could you please edit your answer and add the new information you got from MFA to your answer *(you've commented that some days ago)*

Comment: @Kermani I did mean Timatic. I send a request about the information about Qeshm and Kish and they did answer me but as I said no change has happened till now.

Comment: @Kermani and about the new information do you mean something more than what I said on Oct 10th?

Comment: @samane, As I understood you said that  **Timatic** confirmed **nothing has been changed until now**, if yes, the user *Crazydre* was right and they need to change their information ([here](https://goo.gl/sT4vxi)) because  they believe for Qeshm Visa is required. 

About editing your answer, yes, I mean that;  You had said on October 10th: **our rep in Tehran went directly to MFA and you can be 100 percent sure of being able to visit Qeshm without visa and guide as an american citizen with the direct flight from DXB.** it is helpful and you should add it to the answer

Comment: @Kermani You misunderstood me, Timatic didn't confirmed anything yet. Although they answered my first request which I asked them to correct the information, I didn't get any answer to my second request which I wanted to send them the whole new information about Iran visa process that is going to change very soon. So however I am sure about the MFA information I'm waiting for Timatic answer.

Comment: @Connie Timatic has been updated, see my answer.

Comment: @samane You Need to call the MFA again. Apparently the visa-free provision does not apply to Americans, according to the Timatic update (see my answer)

Answer (score 14):

As per [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), used by airlines and based on information the Iranian immigration authority gives to IATA, you **do** need a visa, which, for an American, will involve having to get a guide if the Interests section says so (since that's where you apply)

UPDATE: [Timatic now says](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IR&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=vs&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C):

> Visa exemptions:
>    Passengers arriving at Kish (KIH) and Qeshm (GSM) islands
>     for a maximum stay of 14 days.
>
> - **This does not apply** to nationals of Afghanistan,
>     Bangladesh, **Canada**, Colombia, India, Iraq, Jordan,
>     Pakistan, Somalia and **USA**.
> - This does not apply to passengers with a **British** passport.

UPDATE 2: Fred mentioned a travel agent named Mona, who said Americans can definitely enter Qeshm visa-free.

The very same Mona now told me via e-mail (today):

> First of all thank you very much for your concern and helpful tip. **The problem is Iran MFA rules are changing all the time, one day they ask for visa in Qeshm and one day they don't. That's why we do not recommend any US citizen to travel Qeshm and Kish without visa and guide until [the MFA] are confident about visa rules**. But we try to lower their cost by hiring cheap guides and skip other unessential cost.

In addition, Timatic consistently says the visa exemption does **not** apply to Americans.

Comment: @pnuts If you put a different nationality into Timatic, e.g. Italian you get "...can obtain a visa on arrival for a max. stay of 30 days at Gheshm Island (GSM)...". That indicates that this answer is likely correct

Comment: @pnuts It was wrong here: https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/middle-east/iran/visa-on-arrival-at-kermanshah-s-airport

Comment: @pnuts Well, if countries are lazy to alert IATA of changes (and many are) then Timatic may not reflect those changes. That said, it is correct in the vast majority of cases, but in my spare time I often dig for errors and report them to Timatic (I have a contact guy in the team). Just today I reported two errors. However, unless I can find a clear source from an immigration website which isn't obviously outdated, I personally assume Timatic has the correct info.

Comment: Does she need to have an authorized guide in free zones like Qeshm in Iran?!

Comment: @Kermani She needs a guide to get an Iranian visa (unless the interests section says something else), and to go to Qeshm an Iranian visa is required.

Comment: Excuse me, I did not get, what is **interests section**?

Comment: @Kermani Iran and the US have no diplomatic relations, so the US has no Iranian embassy. Therefore, visas, consular services etc. are handled at the Iranian interests section, located in the Pakistani embassy

Comment: Thanks, I knew Iran relationship with the US is handled by Switzerland embassy in Iran. I hope she can travel easier in Iran. You know, having an authorized guide in Iran make the trip more expensive, that is **one of** the reasons British, Canadian, and American avoid traveling to Iran

Comment: @Crazydre I really appreciate all of the work you have done with this question and the updating of Timatic. It is not going to work out for me to go to Qeshm in February (not enough vacation days to accommodate an extremely long trip to and back) but when I am able to visit, I feel confident now that my travel to and arrival on Qeshm will go smoothly.

Comment: @Connie You misunderstood me. It says Americans **cannot** enter Qeshm visa-free. See my answer update

Comment: @Crazydre...I did misunderstand. Thanks for pointing that out. This is unsurprisingly complicated, hahhaha. But I do appreciate the efforts to help sort this out.

Answer (score 4):

You can only avail the visa free travel if:

1. You are flying directly to the island.
2. You are staying for less than 14 days.

Since the only way to fly directly to the island is from Dubai, you first have to make your way to Dubai, and then hop on a flight to Qeshm. It takes about 40 minutes.

**All other travel to the island requires a normal visa for Iran**

A few more tips that might be handy:

- There are conflicting reports regarding communication. If you are on a roaming line (that works in Iran) you may only be able to receive and not make any outbound calls. Messaging (SMS) will work without issues.
- You have to make sure you have enough cash with you, as all hotels will require a cash deposit before renting out any rooms.

Comment: My next question becomes, where do I find current information about flights between Dubai and Qeshm? I have looked at Mahan Air, Iran Air, Qeshm Air.  Some websites are under construction, some don't have information that far in advance.

Comment: The only way to get there from Dubai is via Qeshm Air; but their website [qeshm-air.com](http://qeshm-air.com) is only available in Farsi. It doesn't matter if it were in English though, cause the _reservation site_ which is [`4764.ir`](http://www.4764.ir) ... is also only available in Farsi. Your only recourse would be to contact their GSA in Dubai at +9742278787

Answer (score 0):

I am an American. I have also been to Iran. This summer, I would like to go to Qeshm because I don't want to travel with a mandated tour guide.

I contacted a travel agency in Iran (https://1stquest.com), and I have exchanged several emails with Mona, who is a travel agent there. She has been very helpful. She called the MFA for me, and they confirmed that Americans do not need a visa to travel to Kish or Qeshm. She will be booking my hotels there and helping me with all my other travel arrangements in Iran.

Comment: You are very likely to be denied boarding if you attempt to travel without a visa. Even if it is true that you don't need a visa to visit Qeshm, the airlines won't be aware of this. As stated elsewhere in this question, the official information they've been given by the MFA is that Americans _do_ need a visa.

Comment: Fred, you **need** to ask Mona to contact Timatic at timediting@iata.org. Like Michael said, if the databse usn't updated, it could very well destroy your travel plans

Comment: Look at my update. I e-mailed the very same Mona